# How to sort a data base Table swift 3?

Tags: database, sorting, core-data, swift3

I have data base table Name "calculationAxisAll" and I have 40 rows in that and I have a column name "AxisType" I want to sort "calculationAxisAll" Table Data that If my 'AxisType' is Not Same.

```
calculationAxisAll = CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance.fetchAllCalculationOfTest(testID: Test!.testID!)
```

So Here I have 40 rows of a testID and I want to remove duplicate element and want to sort it using swift 3?

```
calculationAxisAll.filter()

for calculationAxis in calculationAxisAll {         
    //calculationAxis
    Helper.sharedInstance.Print(calculationAxis.parentAxis as AnyObject)
}
```

So I will get only those rows.

How can I do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in core data with a sortDescriptor if you are using an SQL store. If you try you will get the error `(LHS and RHS both keypaths)`  - which means that you can sort or query based on values that stored in the database.  40 entities is very little.  Fetch all of the entities and then do an in memory filter and sort.

Comment: So you mean I will fetch 40 entities and I can't fetch by column wise ?

Comment: There are no such things as columns in core data.  There are properties of an object.  You can sort and filter based on the properties of an object just like could with any object.

Comment: OK Thanks to explain.